# Listing multiple items using EmberJS 2.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a basic app having using the Fixture Data Adapter and have a model with some basic seed data.

I am having an issue getting the new emberjs 2.0 to list multiple items in a model. The objects are loaded and showing in them ember inspector but are not looping through and displaying in the browser. I have been able to list one at a time but when i switch to adding multiple items it is blank. Any help would be great.

I have updated with some more information. Here is the route for the list i am trying to list out.

```
<!--dashboard/route.js -->

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
return this.store.findAll('dashboard');
}
});
```

Here is the template file

```
 <!-- dashboard/template.hbs -->
<tbody>
     <tr>
        {{#each dashboards as |dashboard|}}
         <td>dashboards.status</td>
         <td>dashboards.orderid</td>
        {{/each}}
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I think I have everything setup right but cant get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: that repo is completely empty... We can't help you with that. Please provide code snippets of what you are trying to do.

Comment: The repo is now populated, but tossing an entire repo and asking someone to go hunt down the problem is a little unfair.  Like QuantumLicht asked, please provide code snippets, or at least explain which files etc.

Comment: Hey Guys sorry about that I added the main snippets back into the question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try for the model hook. It doesn't need to be a hash.

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.findRecord('dashoard', 2);
}
```

And if you want to return all the dashboards

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('dashoard');
}
```

Then in dashboard/template.hbs

```
    {{order-list dashboards=model}}
```

Now you have access to all your dashboards in your component

```
 {{#each dashboards as |dashboard|}}
    <td>dashboard.status</td>
    <td>dashboard.orderid</td>
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out I am away from my desk but Ill let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch something in a model, it sets the `model` property on the respective controller.

So, instead of looping through `dashboards`, you need to do this:

```js
<tbody>
     <tr>
        {{#each model as |dashboard|}}
         <td>dashboards.status</td>
         <td>dashboards.orderid</td>
        {{/each}}
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

An alternative is to use the `setupController` hook to set up the `dashboards` property on the controller. Something like this:

```js
setupController (controller, model) {
  this._super(...arguments)
  controller.set('dashboards', model)
}
```

This isn't necessary; you're basically creating a `dashboards` alias that points to `model`. So, now, when you loop through `dashboards`, it loops through the `model`.

You can find more about how a controller is set up here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/setting-up-a-controller/